# Cannot build Newtonsoft.Json.Tests with Mono 4 due to inaccessible internal structs and classes

Tags: json.net

For Fedora, we want to build Newtonsoft.Json for Mono 4.
It would probably be nice to run the tests as well.
But when building Newtonsoft.Json.Tests.Net40.csproj, we get errors like this:

`` Utilities/DateTimeUtilsTests.cs(56,24): error CS0122: `Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.StringReference' is inaccessible due to its protection level ``

So checking the source code:
https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Tests/Utilities/DateTimeUtilsTests.cs#L56
https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/StringReference.cs#L30

StringReference is defined as `internal struct`.

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/7c5ka91b.aspx, "internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly"

So how is this ever going to work?
What am I missing?
Does this work on MS.NET, but not on Mono?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internals is visible not only to the assembly where they defined, but also to friendly assemblies. About friendly assemblies you can read in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0tke9fxk(en-us,vs.80).aspx)

In the source code they are defined [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/e8f4a3b651af0cafc863cf6a4c7ec9c3e2088222/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs#L60) and [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/e8f4a3b651af0cafc863cf6a4c7ec9c3e2088222/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs#L63)

Possible you try to run tests with signed version of NewtonSoft.Json.dll and it has different public key from defined in the source (because you signed assembly with your own *.snk file) and this is the reason why Tests assembly does not see internals in the main assembly.